# Access-Control-Allow-Origin in Chrome doesn't work, but in FF works

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, http, google-chrome

I have some code (below) in my html file, I have second file from which I want to load content. Both files are in the same location

```
<div id="mainMenu"></div>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#mainMenu').load('menu.html');
    });
</script>
```

Everything works great in FireFox, but I have some problem in Chrome: content doesn't appear. Under developer tools in Chrome I see this information about 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'. There is screen

I don't use sever code, just HTML and jQuery

[image]

What should I do to resolve this problem? Any idea?

Comment: It's failing in the OPTIONS request, can you show us your serverside code?

Comment: There is no server code, I use only HTML+jQuery. How can I can change request type, use $.post(), coult be solution?

Comment: http://www.chrome-allow-file-access-from-file.com/

Comment: @A.Wolff: your tip is great! Please write it as answer, then I mark it as solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set a local server to serve page because google chrome doesn't allow access by default to local files. However, you could still change chrome setting using option:

```
--allow-file-access-from-files
```

See here for more explanation: http://www.chrome-allow-file-access-from-file.com/

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to execute a file and request on localhost.

Try to run this file on localhost (with wamp or local server), not only executing the html. There should not be any cross-origin problem.

Answer (score 0):

Preview your website in a **local web-server environent (localhost)**

As your console the file path is from your local drive,

Setup a `localhost` using any webserver module and test your website using `http://`

**For Eg:**

**Use**

`http://localhost/yourwebsite/`

**instead of**

```
D:/yourwebsite/
```

You can use wamp or xamp to setup a local environment.